# SQL Server Comparison

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ddl, visual-studio-2012, change-management

I am merging two different versions of a database. I want to add some specific fields from source database to destination, so I used Visual Studio to do that. It does the job quite well but only table level, which means it checks for the table if the table is not available in the destination, it creates.

But my problem is:

In the old database in a specific table I have a `Name` column with `NVARCHAR(50)` mean while in the new database table I have same `Name` column with `NVARCHAR(100)` datatype.

Now I want to ignore this column level comparison only for this specific table field.

Visual Studio allows me to do this at the table level only, not at the column level. Can anyone tell me how it would be possible?